# Why isn't my data printed in the dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to make a function that will generate a dataframe/table with data about movies based on a search word from imdb. However the dataframe only shows "NaN".

I can see the data when I try to print it, writing:

```
print(r)
```

But my data frame shows nothing.

My function is like this:

```
def get_movies(title):
    r = search_omdb(title)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = r, index = ['imdbID'], columns = ['Poster', 'Title', 'Type', 'Year']) 
    df.index.name = 'imdbID'
    df = df.sort_values('Year', ascending = True) 
    return df

get_movies('hamlet')
```

This is the outcome:

```
    Poster  Title   Type    Year
imdbID              
imdbID  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: what is your r , can you print it ?

Comment: Yes, it's {'Search': [{'Title': 'Hamlet', 'Year': '1996', 'imdbID': 'tt0116477', 'Type': 'movie', 'Poster': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA4OTM4NzMxOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDY1OTM2MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg'}, {'Title': 'Hamlet', 'Year': '1990', 'imdbID': 'tt0099726', 'Type': 'movie', 'Poster': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjI5OTgwNTc3M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDY1NTk4NjE@._V1_SX300.jpg'}) etc.

Comment: Try `df = pd.DataFrame(r)`?

Comment: I can see the data when doing this, but as soon as I try to add the dataframe it says NaN

Answer (score 0):

Hamlet in your `r` per your comment is capitalized and in your code is not.

Comment: It doesn't matter because the search word 'hamlet' is just there to search imdb, the data contains 'Hamlet' based on the search findings